# Read a webcomic about demons with multiple horns

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

Read this between 2014-2016 and can’t remember much except for humans being fodder for these demons who could originally be one horned and level up in a way? The protagonist was a three horned something! And female - another character I can remember was a male scientist but generally can’t remember much! I also remember it was based around goats etc and there was a giant goat in a few panels

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)